# examples for languages of natural numbers

Tags: turing-machines

I need to find examples for language $L_i$  $i\in[1,3]$ of natural numbers that is:

1. $L_1\in$ $RE \backslash R$
2. $L_2\in$ $coRE\backslash R$
3. $L_3\in$ $\overline{ R \cup RE}$

My idea was in any case to take a language in the desired language class, and find some sort of function from the language to the natural numbers. But I do not know if this is the right way to approach the problem, and how exactly to find such function.

Comment: Are you sure you phrased the question correctly? By the first condition $L$ must be in $RE$, by the second in $coRE$, but then it would be in $R = RE \cap coRE$, which is contradicted by all three conditions.

Comment: I need example for each case. Not necessarily the same L for each case

Comment: Ah! Sorry, you did say "examples". At least the first example is a completely standard thing that is in every textbook on computability theory.

Comment: and the second? is there a way to approach this kind of questions? I'm taking the course and we never really done question like this.

Comment: I don't think you can just solve the first one withouth having some training in computability theory, but if you do have such training, you will be shown the solution beacuse it is a classic one (the halting set). The second problem is dual to the first one, so you should be able to dualize the solution (think about taking complements). The third one maybe requires some ingenuity to combine $L_1$ and $L_2$ from the first two problems to get a solution of the third.